# Wordpress: Create filter in nav menu

Tags: javascript, wordpress, filter

I have this wordpress site: https://gadgetgod.de

There is a filter on my site which was given by the theme which filters all my posts.

I want to put such a filter in the nav menu of the site. How do I do that?

[The problem visualized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j04mp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose of that kind of filter in the nav menu?

Without seeing the backend I cannot be 100% sure, but that filter is probably provided by Visual Composer. You should be able to verify that by opening the page for edit. You should see some kind of Visual Composer entity above the grid that it is filtering. And as far as I know, Visual Composer won't allow you to add that kind of pagination/filter to your menus.

Comment: Yes, you can add that filter to a post display thing from Visual Composer. But is it possible to recreate sth like this that only shows a category of posts?